# How does one synthesise 2-Monoglycerides from Triglycerides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

How does one synthesise 2-monoglycerides from triglycerides with additional ingredients if necessary?

My first instinct would be to add a catalyst for the reaction of $triglyceride \rightarrow 3 FA + glycerol$ (FA=fatty acid; for instance a catalyst could be sodium hydroxide) and then add additional glycerol so as to cause the reaction: $FA + glycerol \rightarrow 2$-$monoglyceride $ to occur but I just wanted to ask if this is true because to me this seems too simple to be true.

Comment: It is too simple to be true. In such way you will get mixture of 1- and 2-monoglicerides with some products of further reactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I have learnt is by taking a page out of the human body's book and using pancreatic lipase, found in pancreatic juice, to catalyse the reaction:

$triglyceride+ 2H_2 O \rightleftharpoons   2$-$monoglyceride+2 FAA$

Where FAA stands for, 'Fatty acid anion.'

If someone has a better answer I'll readily accept it over this one, this is just one method.

Comment: Just a note--we support LaTeX (with a chemistry extension) over here. See http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here